# why i am getting exception mergesort in java?

Tags: java, mergesort

I am unable to understand why i am getting Exception.I Checked result at each stage but still couldn't find errors.

Temp is an array in which i want to add elements which will be sorted.

A is an array that contains the elements which are to be sorted
package app;

public class MergeSortDemo

{

```
    public static void  mergesort(int A[],int temp[],int left,int right)

    {

        int mid;

        if(right>left) //why u need to check this  base case always

        {

            //System.out.println(right);

            //System.out.println(left);

            mid=(right+left)/2;

            mergesort(A,temp,left,mid);

            mergesort(A,temp,mid+1,right);

            merge(A,temp,left,mid+1,right);

        }

    }   

    public static void  merge(int A[],int temp[],int left,int mid,int right)

    {

        int i,left_end,size,temp_pos;

        System.out.println(left);

        System.out.println(right);

        left_end=mid-1; 

        System.out.println(left_end);

        temp_pos=left;

        System.out.println(temp_pos);

        size=right-left+1;

        System.out.println(size);

        while((left<=left_end)&&(mid<=right))

        {

            System.out.println(A[left]);

            System.out.println(A[right]);

            System.out.println(A[mid]);

            if(A[left]<=A[mid])

            {

                temp[temp_pos]=A[left];

                System.out.println(A[left]);

                System.out.println("left in temp");


                temp_pos=temp_pos+1;

                left=left+1;

            }

            else

            {

                System.out.println(A[right]);

                System.out.println("right in temp");

                temp[temp_pos]=A[mid];

                temp_pos=temp_pos+1;

                mid=mid+1;

            }

        }

        while(left<=left_end)

        {

            temp[temp_pos]=A[left];

            System.out.println(A[left]);

            System.out.println("left left");

            left=left+1;

            temp_pos=temp_pos+1;

        }

        while(mid<=right)

        {

            temp[temp_pos]=A[mid];

            System.out.println(A[mid]);

            System.out.println("right left");

            mid=mid+1;

            temp_pos=temp_pos+1;

        }

        for(i=0;i<size;i++)

        {

            A[right]=temp[right];

            //System.out.println(A[right]);

            right=right-1;

        }

        for(i=0;i<size;i++)

        {

            System.out.println(A[i]);

        }

    }

public static void main(String s[])

{

    int ar[]={6,3,2,5,4};

    int p[]=new int[ar.length];

    mergesort(ar,p,0,ar.length-1);

}
```

}

OutPutShown here is

```
0    
1    
0    
0    
2    
6    
3    
3    
3
```

Stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" right in temp

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1  //why 
     app.MergeSortDemo.merge(MergeSortDemo.java:81)
     app.MergeSortDemo.mergesort(MergeSortDemo.java:19)
     app.MergeSortDemo.mergesort(MergeSortDemo.java:17)
     app.MergeSortDemo.mergesort(MergeSortDemo.java:17)
     app.MergeSortDemo.main(MergeSortDemo.java:91)
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting - the indentation is inconsistent, and you've got a blank line for every other line. I'm sure that's not how it looks in your editor...

Comment: @JonSkeet Done Do Check it

Comment: No, that code is now looking *horrible*. Please use the preview to check that your post looks sensible before you hit post.

Comment: Pleaes format this slovenly post, and bring out the fact that your exception is `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`.

Comment: @JonSkeet what does the base case which i commented in the code do?

Comment: @JonSkeet Please Check the code do it still need some changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop in your `merge` method looks wrong :

```
        for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
        {
            A[right]=temp[right];
            right=right-1;
        }
```

For example, suppose you call merge with `left=0,mid=1,right=1`.

So `size = right-left+1=2`

This loop will have 3 iterations and `right` would reach `-1` in the last iteration, causing your exception.

The correct loop is probably :

```
        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            A[right]=temp[right];
            right=right-1;
        }
```

EDIT: I just tested it, and that's indeed the problem. After changing `i<=size` to `i<size`, your code produces the correct sorted array :

```
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I Didn't understand the loop here firstly though the ans is correct May u please Explain in detail Secondly why can't we print the elements like for(i=0;i<temp.length;i++){ temp[i] } instead of transfering the contents to A[i]

Comment: @mansikbchawla That loop is a bit awkward. It could have been replaced with a single call to System.arraycopy, since what it does is simply copy part of the temp array to the A array. You have to copy the merged numbers from the temp array to the A array, since the A array is the source of the merge method. The merge method relies on the elements of A from left to mid-1 as well as the elements from mid to right to be sorted. That can only be true if previous calls to merge copied the sorted sub-arrays from temp back to A.